# How to declare an array of objects of different types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a an array with elements representing a HTML form of types TextInput, DateInput, Checkbox and so on.

How do I declare a variable type as an array of elements that can be any of these types?

Something like this

```
(TextInput | DateInput | Checkbox)[]
```

Comment: Are there common properties of the types? If so, I would create a common parent class or interface and that would be the type of the array. Why would you do this?

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
let myArray: Array<TextInput | DateInput | Checkbox> = [];
```

And you can also do:

```
type MyArrayTypes = TextInput | DateInput | Checkbox;
let myArray: MyArrayTypes[] = [];
```

These two ways of defining arrays are equeivalent:

```
let a: number[] = [];
// is just like:
let b: Array<number> = [];
```

But sometimes the 2nd way fits better, like in your case.

Comment: look into `User-Defined Type Guards` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html - you can write custom functions to check the type of something if it could be one of several things - and then the compiler can do some amazing things like look at common properties between types and infer what the object can or can't be since it must be one of the types in your list

Comment: @Simon_Weaver type guard has nothing to do with the question. The OP asked about how to define the type of an array not how to check the type.

Comment: Fair point. I just thought it was a logical next step that might be useful. Rereading I could have been clearer that’s what I meant.